# Super Key requires Fn key to be pressed

Tags: 18.04, alienware

My super key randomly stopped working and I have been trying to rebind my super key. Currently to use the super key I must do (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd>) I am not sure if I set it to this or it switched to this and as a result I couldn't use the super key.

I have an Alienware 17 R4.

I have tried going into the bios and turning on <kbd>Fn lock</kbd> but that did not change the super key.

I believe I need to use xmodmap but i am new to Linux and need an experienced person to help me come up with the exact procedure because the man pages make no scene to me

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am running 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not completely experienced with Linux as of right now and I wasn't that far into installing all the stuff I wanted I just reinstalled a clean version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Apparently, the (`Fn + F6`) disables/enables the super key. found this by trial and error.